# Apache2: Subdomain not working

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I have a problem with my subdomain, which is not working. In my DNS I have the following A record:

cloud.example.net ---------> IP of server

And in my httpd-vhosts.txt I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
 DocumentRoot "c:/apache/htdocs/cloud"
 ServerName cloud.example.net
ErrorLog "logs/cloud.example.net-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/cloud.example.net-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I open cloud.example.net I just get the site of example.net?

Comment: Can you describe the site example.net more? Is it the same IP and server? Different server? What's the DocumentRoot of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config looks fine. Try running `httpd -S` to verify that Apache is recognising the vhost. Did you restart Apache after adding the vhost?

Comment: I did restart apache after adding the host, but apache is not recognising it if i check it with httpd -S

Comment: Can you confirm that `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.txt` is uncommented in the main `httpd.conf` file?